# sort _score desc elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have created a elasticsearch query with function score and `top_hit`. This query will remove the duplicate and return top 1 record for each bucket.

```
GET employeeid/info/_search
{"size": 0, 
  "query" : {
        "function_score" : {
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "employeeID" : "23141A"
                }
            },
            "functions" : [{
                    "linear" : {
                        "AcquiredDate" : {
                            "scale" : "90d",
                            "decay" : 0.5
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "filter" : {
                        "match" : {
                            "name" : "sorna"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor" : 10
                }, {
                    "filter" : {
                        "match" : {
                            "name" : "lingam"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor" : 7
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode" : "replace"
        }
    },
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "field": "employeehash",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {
              "size":1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the expected result, But the problem is i want to sort the result using `_score`.

Following is my simple o/p

```
 {
               "key": "567",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "duplicateDocuments": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 2,
                     "max_score": 0.40220365,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "employeeid",
                           "_type": "info",
                           "_id": "5",
                           "_score": 0.40220365,
                           "_source": {
                              "name": "John",
                              "organisation": "google",
                              "employeeID": "23141A",
                              "employeehash": "567",
                              "AcquiredDate": "2016-02-01T07:57:28Z"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "102",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "duplicateDocuments": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 2.8154256,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "employeeid",
                           "_type": "info",
                           "_id": "8",
                           "_score": 2.8154256,
                           "_source": {
                              "name": "lingam",
                              "organisation": "google",
                              "employeeID": "23141A",
                              "employeehash": "102",
                              "AcquiredDate": "2016-02-01T07:57:28Z"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
```

**Question**:  How to sort _score : desc ?
i have not enabled groovy so i can not use script

Comment: I tried order: {"_score" : desc} but got error

Comment: I tried this too :  "sort" : ["_score":{"order":"desc"}]. but not working

Comment: If you're looking for duplicates, shouldn't `min_doc_count` be 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @Val   i do not want the duplicate records, i want only one record once. meaning if i have doc1, doc2 duplicate i want either one of the doc to be fetched

Comment: @Val, If i give min_doc_count = 2 thn i will not get those records that are unique.  that's why. It gives me the expected result but i want to sort it

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering since I thought you were willing to detect duplicates based on the names you gave to your aggregations.

Comment: @Val, You are corect my question is providing that kind of interpretation.

Comment: Are you certain that you're adding `"sort" : ["_score":{"order":"desc"}]` to your `top_hits` aggregation and not to the main query?

Comment: @Val, Is it possible to sort based on max_score or _score ?

Comment: @Val yes,  "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {
              "size":1,
      "sort": [{"_score":{"order":"desc"}}]
          }
        }  but not working

Comment: Have you increased the size to 2 to make sure that your claim holds? What's the score of the other document? You understand that the sort is "per-bucket" and not across buckets, right?

Comment: @Val,That is the problem, I want to sort accross buckets.

Comment: Then the answer is: That won't work :-) Each bucket holds its own set of documents, which are sorted per-bucket.

Comment: @Val, Is here any other way of doing this?  :(

Comment: @Val, As we see in the simple o/p, I want the doc with "_score" / "max_score"  = 2.8154256 on the top the result, Very first document. so i thought that order by _score desc would work

Comment: You could use another metric sub-aggregation whose value would be based on one field (latest date, etc) of the document and then you could sort your terms aggregation based on that value.